# What is the systematic name of ammonium bisoxalato cuprate (II)?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, coordination-compounds, transition-metals, organometallic-compounds

What is the systematic name of ammonium bisoxalato cuprate(II)?

I already tried $\ce{(NH4)2[Cu(C2O4)2]^{2+}}$ but i am uncertain if that answer is correct.

Comment: The systematic name of ammonium bisoxalatocuprate(II) is *ammonium bisoxalatocuprate(II).* Where is your question?

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean to ask "what is the *chemical formula* of ammonium bisoxalatocuprate(II)", yes? If so, the compound is a salt and should be chargeless.
$$\ce{(NH4)2[Cu(C2O4)]}$$
This is because oxalate is -2 charged and there are two of them making a total of -4, copper is +2 charged, and 2 ammoniums make a total of +2 charge. All of these charges cancel.